# How to make a query act on only one element

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I want to write a query that takes one record in a table and subtracts a value from only one record in a second table.  See the picture below.

Client A ordered 2 of product 1, 1 of product 2, 1 of product 2 (at a later date), 5 of product 3 and 1 of product 4.

He returned 1 of product 1, 1 of product, 1 of product 2, 2 of product 3 and 1 of product 3.

Difference is given in the next column.

[image]

My sql is:

```
SELECT Orders.Client, Orders.[Product #], [Ordered]-[Returned] AS Delta
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Returns ON (Orders.[Product #] = Returns.[Product 
#]) AND (Orders.Client = Returns.Client);
```

But it gives me the following, which is incorrect since Product 2 is acted on four times and product 3 is acted on twice as (5-2) and then again as (5-1).

```
Client  Product #   Delta
 A           1        1
 A           2        0
 A           2        0
 A           2        0
 A           2        0
 A           3        3
 A           3        4
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don’t have an id for each order to match with. Try using Sum and Group by on each table separately and then join them on the grouped columns

```
SELECT o.Client, o.[Product #], sum_ordered - sum_returned
FROM (SELECT Client, [Product #], SUM([Ordered]) AS sum_ordered
      FROM Orders 
      GROUP BY Client, [Product #]) o
JOIN (SELECT Client, [Product #], SUM(returned) AS sum_returned 
      FROM Returns 
      GROUP BY Client, [Product #]) r ON o.Client = r.Client AND o.[Product #] = r.[Product #]
```

Comment: OK, thanks, but for Product 3 I get a delta of 7 when it should be 2.

Comment: If I just calculate the sum of ordered I get 2, 4 and 10 for products 1, 2 and 3.  For the sum of returned I get 1, 4 and 3.

Comment: @Angus My mistake, there is not a 1-to-1 relationship between the two tables. I post an updated answer soon

Comment: @Angus It looks like I missed a ] but you should really try to investigate a syntax error yourself

Comment: Thanks @Joakim for the help.  I couldn't figure out your sql or why it wouldn't work so I just created two queries:  one for the Orders and one for the Returns and just subtracted the results.  I'll just apply it now to over 3 million records.